# Similar libraries across different programming languages

Tags: app, website

### Screenshot

[image]

### Update

**0.1**

- Add the tagWiki like for each tag;
- Add "like" button to collect votes so that to rerank results accordingly;
- Update the UI by smaller the blank space to make it look more compact.

**0.2**

- Add a new function called comparsion i.e., compare similar libraries by find sentences in Stack Overfow which mention both libraries. You can access to it by clicking **comparison** button;
- Realign the UI elements.

### About

When developers switch from one language to another language, they always asks questions about counterpart libraries to the one that he is familiar with in the old language, e.g.,

- [Java's Mahout equivalent in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819437/javas-mahout-equivalent-in-python)
- [Library similar to BeautifulSoup and “HTML Agility Pack” but for C or Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405658/library-similar-to-beautifulsoup-and-html-agility-pack-but-for-c-or-java)
- [Python equivalent of D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977517/python-equivalent-of-d3-js)
- [Java equivalent for Python NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478263/java-equivalent-for-python-nltk)
- [Crypto++ equivalent in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493808/crypto-equivalent-in-c)

Although it is not allowed to propose such questions in Stack Overflow (off-topic), there are still many similar questions and they are always with high scores.

Motivated by such questions, we propose an approach to automatically answer these analogy questions by applying [Word2Vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) algorithm with incorporating the [knowledge graph](https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/) to the tags in Stack Overflow.

Thus, given a library(tag), the [website](https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/similartech) can render:

- No more than 4 libraries in six different programming languages (maybe less), java, c#, python, c++, javascript, php;
- The tagwiki and their asking trend of these recommended libraries in Stack Overflow;

### Website

Our website can be visited in [**https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/similartech**](https://graphofknowledge.appspot.com/similartech)

### Contact

For any questions, bugs, suggestions, please leave a message in this post or contact me in my email wchccy@gmail.com.